# Dog with open wound on leg and no vet available

Tags: dogs, medicines, infections, strays, wound-care

I found this dog in a graveyard, probably waiting to die, with a huge open wound on its backside 2 days ago. I've been feeding it, helping it regain its strength but I'm concerned, the wound may get infected. What should I do? I live in a small town. We don't have vets that tend to canines here. How do I tend to the wound without hurting the dog or getting bitten myself?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thete seems to be a black spot in the center of the wound. Is it more like a scab (dried blood) or is the soft tissue turning black?

Comment: None. It's an open wound and i dont know how deep since I haven't been able to examine the wound properly at all. It took a lot of work just to even take that photo because the dog wouldn't move from it's resting place. That black spot isn't actually a spot but more like a hole.

Answer (score 3):

The wound is clearly *very* infected and it's only natural the dog turns it away from you. Please don't try to touch it, it may provoke a (defensive) attack.

You also have to realize that the dog may not survive. If the tissue inside the wound dies off (called a necrosis), it cannot heal and must be surgically removed. It might already be too late to avoid a [sepsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepsis) due to bacteria from the infection spreading through the whole body.

To fight the infection and relieve the pain, I suggest you go to a pharmacy and ask specifically for one of these drugs:

- carprofen (Novox or Rimadyl)
- deracoxib (Deramaxx)
- firocoxib (Previcox)
- meloxicam (Metacam)

All of them are anti-inflammatory drugs and listed as safe for dogs by [WebMD](https://pets.webmd.com/dogs/guide/dog-pain-medications#1). Using human medication like ibuprofen or aspirin can lead to kidney failure in pets.

The pharmacists may ask why you need those (at least they should if they do their job right). Show them the pictures you've taken and let them estimate the proper dosage of the pills.

Give the dog the proper dosage twice a day (or according to what the pharmacist and packaging say) and always together with food. The stomach should not be empty when taking the pills. If the dog doesn't like the pills, coat them in something tasty like cream cheese or a soft sausage. Continue the treatment for as long as the packaging says it's safe.

Comment: Thanks alot. I must add though, the dog keeps on licking at the wound. Doesn't dog saliva have healing properties? It's been 3 days and the dog stood up and moved around for the first time today on it's own. Thats when i became certain of the wound. Incase if the dog does somehow allows me to tend to it's wound, what should i do? Clear the area with a spray bottle and apply an ointment of some kind along with the oral medication that you've advised?

Comment: @HamidSabir I wouldn't touch the wound if I were you. The risk of being bitten is too high (especially if you try to flush it with a desinfactant, which hurts). The benefit is probably low because the bacteria are in the tissue, not on top and you're not properly trained to tend such a wound. The dog should be able to keep dirt out. Just take care it isn't infected with maggots as well.

Comment: I don't think dog spit has healing properties, but the act of licking promotes blood flow to the wound. Which aids healing